# Is there a way (or a save) to just play the final pursuit in NFS:MW?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

After finishing the game, you can replay all races except blacklist events and the final pursuit.

Is there a way to just play that one pursuit?

Answer (score 3):

- Backup your save game just beforore the last race and then overwrite it if You want to replay it. I played this game some time ago, so I dont remember exact path, but is is somewhere in documents, just search for it.
- Last race savegame might be somewhere on the net. Ask in some Most Wanted forums.
- Use save game editor.

Comment: Here's an upvote. 15 more reputation awaits you if you can come up with the save path and/or a link to the relevant save file :)

Comment: There is a save, I assume what You want is the last one http://www.needforspeedsavegames.com/savegames/Most_Wanted . Is it the one You want? It worked for me, I don't know if it is the race You mean, I have neither finished the game nor this race. :) **How to make it work** After I extracted the file, I had to rename this savefile to name my profile name (should be the file in alredy mentioned save game directory) and it worked. Good Luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

The path to the savegames is (Windows Vista):
**C:\Users{your_user_name}\Documents\NFS Most Wanted**

Inside that folder you got the folders with your profile names. Copy the ones you want, and then just paste them when you want to play the final game again. :)

If you're Windows XP or Seven, I think the folder **NFS Most Wanted** is also inside your Documents, but I cannot confirm.

Hope I helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

---

### Window vista or Newer

save path

> C:/users/{UserName}/My Documents/NFS Most Wanted

---

### Windows xp or earlier

save path

> C:\Documents and Settings{User name}\My Documents\NFS Most Wanted

Backup your NFS Folder every time you wanna put Marker now

Replace this one with the existing path folder to play from the Marked Position or backup position

This will apply at any stage Not only for Last one

and also if YOU Have **MULTIPLE PROFILES**

You shall back only **YOUR TARGETED PROFILE**

Answer (score 0):

Search for your profile in My Documents(I think that it's in Nfs Most Wanted folder,if you don't find it,use Search). Then,copy your profile(just before the pursuit) to another place(copy the whole folder!). When you want to play again the pursuit,copy the profile back,but don't forget to copy the profile that is already there to another place.